# Inherit jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I need to inherit from a jQuery object to create my own object with additional functions.

I have tried this with two custom objects and it works:

```
var MotherClass = function(name){
   this.name = name;
}

MotherClass.prototype.getName = function(){
   console.log(this.name);
};

var mother = new MotherClass("mam");
mother.getName(); //=> mam

var ChildClass = function(propName){
   MotherClass.call(this, propName);
}

ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(MotherClass.prototype);

ChildClass.prototype.getChildName = function(){
   console.log(this.name + " child");
};

var child = new ChildClass("child");
child.getName(); //=> child
child.getChildName(); //=> child child
```

The child class calls correctly the constructor of mother class. Now i would like to make the same case with jQuery.

But with jQuery, I don't know how to call the constructor of jQuery...

```
var ValueCounter = function (selector) {
   $.call(this, selector);
}

ValueCounter.prototype = Object.create(jQuery.prototype);

ValueCounter.prototype.dataCounter = function(){
    console.log(this.data('counter')); 
    // => this is equals to [] and not my div; 
    //so the return is "undefined" and note the value of my data.
};

var toto = new ValueCounter("#toto");
toto.dataCounter();
```

EDIT:

Requirements:

- I would create an object inherits from jQuery.
- Add functions and/or properties only at this object.
- Use my object like jQuery object (myObject.addClass(...))

I would these functionalities to use easiest my object, and not create a simple object with inside a property "$element" because all the time you write: myObject.$element.jQueryFunctions. It is too long.

I just would write:

```
myObject.jQueryFunctions
myObject.personnelFunctions
myObject.personnelProperties
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There is probably a better way....

Comment: I prefer inherit from my jquery object because is easiest to write code:

    var toto = new ValueCounter("#toto");
    toto.addClass("myClass");

add not write this:
    toto.$element.addClass("myClass");

I would add functions only for this kind of element and not all jquery objects.

Answer (score 0):

As appear no additional properties added to `ValueCounter` , simplest approach would be to alias jQuery to `ValueCounter` , use `$.fn.extend` to set `dataCounter` as method of jQuery object . See also [Building staeful jQuery plugins](http://Building%20stateful%20jQuery%20plugins)

```js
var ValueCounter = jQuery;
$.fn.extend({
  dataCounter: function() {
    console.log(this.data("counter"));
    return this
  }
});

var toto = new ValueCounter("body");
toto.dataCounter();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body data-counter="0">
```

> Requirements:
>
> - I would create an object inherits from jQuery.
> - Add functions and/or properties only at this object.
> - Use my object like jQuery object (myObject.addClass(...))

Try using `for` loop to set `jQuery` properties to object , alias `fn.init()` to `$` at object

```js
var obj = Object.create({
  "abc": 123,
  "color":"olive",
  "def": function() {
    return this.abc
  },
  "el": "body",
  "method": function() {
    return this
  }
});

for (prop in window["jQuery"]) {
  // alias `$` to `fn.init` at `obj`
  if(prop === "fn") { obj["$"] = window["jQuery"][prop].init };
  obj[prop] = window["jQuery"][prop]
}

obj.$(obj.el)
.html(obj.abc)
.css("color", obj.color);

console.log(obj.method())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body>abc</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but this is not exactly what I want. Because in this case, all jquery objects can use this function.

    $('mySelector').dataCounter(); // this code works and I wouldn't

Comment: @MatthieuKaiser Not certain what requirement of Question is ?